# Equivalent Resistance Between Two Points in a Wye Network

Tags: electrical-engineering, heat-transfer, electrical, thermal-conduction

I am interested in learning how to calculate the equivalent resistance between two points in a wye circuit for application to thermal networks (i.e. I'd like to calculate the equivalent thermal resistance between nodes with two conductive paths). [image]

Say I am interested in calculating the equivalent resistance between the following nodes: (1) Node 1 and Node 4; (2) Node 1 and Node 3; (3) Node 3 and Node 4 for arbitrary values of R1, R2, and R3. Is there an analytical expression for such a calculation, or a way to determine the equivalent resistances? If you could also provide a link to some reference for my review, that would also be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the external resistance at each node ? This must be defined.